# Why is he bankrupt?

Tags: riddle

One day, a man named Jonathan Doesar was pushing his car and stopped when he reached a hotel. At that point, he knew he was bankrupt. Why?

Comment: 33 second answer letsgo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He was pushing a car

> in monopoly

and then when he stopped at

> the hotel, he didn't have money and then he went bankrupt.

Comment: dang, that was fast

Comment: i was sniped so hard

Comment: It's okay I was sniped countless times by Phylyp it was depressing :P

Comment: you've got to be kidding me

Answer (score 0):

He is:

> playing monopoly, the car is his player token, the hotel indicates he owes a bunch of money to the player owning that real estate

Comment: How is this different from the answer that @NL628 posted above?

Comment: @puzzledPig possibly gives more explanation ;)